# how to make performance testing and load testing for internet portal before deploying to production?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, performance, load-testing

i deployed new sharepoint 2013 farm for our internet portal and now we finished customization and deployed locally. Here before going to production how i will do  performance testing and load testing?

and also i want to know how many users request per second ,latency , average number of users per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio 2013/2015 Web performance and load tests feature:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC381

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710162.aspx

For the question, "how many users request per second ,latency , average number of users per day" you can use IIS Logs

http://todosharepoint.blogspot.com.ar/2014/08/exportar-los-logs-del-iis-de-sharepoint.html
http://todosharepoint.blogspot.com.ar/2014/08/evaluando-nuestro-rps-actual-de-los.html